# Why is RenderAction referring to an action method on the current controller despite a different controller specified in the parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to render the action method called "IndexBlah" on the controller "ImageShare" using:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction(actionName: "IndexBlah", controllerName: "ImageShare"); }
```

But this results in the following exception:

> A public action method 'IndexBlah' was not found on controller 'Web.Site.Controllers.BannerContentBlockController'.

This exception specifically mentions not finding the action method on **BannerContentBlockController**, which is the current controller being utilised. But since my call to RenderAction specifies *"ImageShare"* as the second parameter in RenderAction, shouldn't it be calling that controller?

**Additional info:**

If I place the same code:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction(actionName: "IndexBlah", controllerName: "ImageShare"); }
```

On the parent page, it works correctly. It only fails as described when within the partial view BannerContentBlockModel.cshtml

I'm still unsure why this is an issue but might help narrow the scenario.

Comment: Works for me. Maybe some routing issue?

Comment: Create an ActionLink on the same page using the same input then hover see what you get for your Url.

Comment: @rism interestingly, that works.. @Html.ActionLink("Test link", "IndexBlah", "ImageShare") results in <a href="/ImageShare/IndexBlah">Test link</a> - so I still don't understand why the original RenderAction with the same parameters doesn't work.

Comment: Probably need to show us your cshtml and cs including your route configs.

Comment: @rism the route configs are pretty standard, but see my additional info in question as the problem only occurs within the "BannerContentBlockModel" partial view. Here's my route config anyway:
    routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "Web.Site.Controllers" });